# Is it impossible for Goku and Vegeta to turn Legendary Super Saiyan?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

So from the spoilers of Dragon Ball Super Broly, apparently,

> for a second Vegeta's hair turns green

Is it impossible for Goku and Vegeta to turn Legendary Super Saiyan? In the non canon movie (the original movie) it was made apparently that it was, but with the Dragon Ball Super series/ Dragon Ball Super Broly, is there anything that proves that Goku and Vegeta can't turn into Legendary Super Saiyan?

Answer (score 1):

Vegeta's har does turn green. Also, when Goku transforms into Super Saiyan Blue, there is a tinge of green aura. I believe this has to do with the animation and it isn't a new transformation.

Broly's Legendary Super Saiyan transformation is similar to that of Kale's. If you look at the way these two attained their respective transformations, they both originated similarly to the regular Super Saiyan transformations. In the sense, Broly transformed to this level when he was angry and struggling against Gogeta and Kale transformed to this level when she was angry.

Hence, I believe Goku and Vegeta cannot use this form and the transformation is solely based on the genetics of the Saiyan.

Answer (score -1):

Goku and Vegeta cannot use this form,
In the storyline of dragon ball, there are two types of Saiyans.

The Blood of the Tainted
and
The Blood of the Defeated

the tainted Saiyans can turn into SS God and the Defeated have the rage power/ green ssj